# How to debug apps in iPhone?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have fresh MacBook and a new iOS development profile. Now, what are the new ways to sign a provisioning profile to debug and build in iPhone?What I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

There is complete guide for provision profile.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty strait forward. In Xcode, go to 'Preferences -> Accounts' and add your account. When you select your device as run target, there will appear a dialog after you hit CMD+R. It will ask you to fix issues and when you approve that, everything will be done for you in background by Xcode.

For more about Provisioning Profiles, Certificates etc., I recommend you to read [App Distribution Quick Start Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013839).